# Logging hit count ACEs that are used in NAT rules on email

Tags: cisco-asa

Can anyone tell me all the commands that I need to enable logging on my email, hit count on access control entries that I use in static NAT with port translation, on my ASA 5525-X?

I tried with:

```
logging enable
logging timestamp
logging mail errors
logging from-address asa@xxx.xxx
logging recipient-address asa@xxx.xxx level errors
smtp-server x.x.x.x
logging message 106100 level errors
```

and of course at the end of ACEs I added "log"

Hit count is rising, but I don have emails.

Comment: Does that e-mail address actually exist on the mail server? I don't see the `level` keyword on the recipient address command: `logging recipient-address <e-mail_address> [severity_level]`.

Comment: logging recipient-address asa@xxx.xxx level errors, yes, when I puted here level informational, I had 1000 emails in few seconds.But I dont need those informations. Only log of ace hits.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Your comment says you got 1000 emails for `informational`, but your question says you don't get any for errors. Are you sure that there are what it considers errors happening?

Comment: Im not sure if the error level is good. For receiving a hit on ACE. I only need information when ACE is hit. I dont need rest of logging informations.

Comment: You probably want to use a syslog server and an application which gives you exactly what you want. When you log, you are going to get every message for the logging level selected. A proper syslog server and an application to use the resulting data sounds like what you need.

Comment: Im not sure. See this document. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/acl_logging.html .... It about acl logging. And syslog server is same as email ... both are just destinations for logs.

Comment: I just need proper configuration that is tested...

Comment: The proper way is to use a syslog server and an application to parse the resulting data. Message `106100` is an `information` level message, and you can change it to `error` level, but it will not change for any existing ACE, and all errors will end up in the log, not just the matches. "_An optional syslog level (0 - 7) can be specified for the generated syslog messages (106100). If no level is specified, the default level is 6 (informational) for a new ACE. If the ACE already exists, then its current log level remains unchanged._"

Comment: Last comment, post like an answer, I will give you a bounty reward.

Comment: OK. I just did that.

Comment: Thanks for answers, it helped me a lot to understand how system works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way is to use a syslog server and an application to parse the resulting data. Message 106100 is an information level message, and you can change it to error level, but it will not change for any existing ACE, and all errors will end up in the log, not just the matches.

> An optional syslog level (0 - 7) can be specified for the generated
>   syslog messages (106100). If no level is specified, the default level
>   is 6 (informational) for a new ACE. If the ACE already exists, then
>   its current log level remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Change what ever rule hit you want to send email to the specified level you want emails sent out this may require you to create a separate access rule if you only want it when it's specific traffic. Change the severity for the new specific rule's severity level and set the email alert configuration to that.

Edit for configuration. it would look something like this:

```
      access-list Outside_access_in line 12 extended permit tcp host 192.168.1.1 host 172.16.1.26 eq smtp  log 1 interval 300
  access-list Outside_access_in line 13 extended permit tcp any host 172.16.1.26 eq smtp 
  logging from-address asa@place.com
  logging recipient-address alerts@mycomany.com level Errors
  smtp-server 172.16.1.26
```

Comment: Can you send me some configuration example, just to make your replay more understandable.

Comment: You just need to configure the rule you want alerts on at a higher level and then have email alerts sent for that level.